# How to get data-id of a div inside of a jQuery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have divs within multiple jQuery dialogs. I want to execute a function on opening the jQuery dialog. For that I need to acquire the div's data-id.
The divs are named dynamically. When I get the data-id, I need to execute the network+data-id.fit() function.

The dialog looks sth. like this:

```
<div class = "ui-dialog-titlebar ..."></div>
<div class = "info ui-dialog-content ...">
   <p>..</p>
   <div data-id = "'identifier'">
      <div class = "vis-network"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The dialog options:

```
$( ".info" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  open: function() {
    var networkDataId = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(networkDataId);
    network.fit();
    },
  height: 600,
  width: 1000
});
```

Comment: Your snippet is a bit minimalistic. Are you sure `this` in your context is the element that has the data-id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function on your `.info` selector to detect which element has a `data-id` attribute : `$('.info').find('[data-id]').data('id');`

```
$( ".info" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  open: function() {
    var networkDataId = $('.info').find('[data-id]').data('id');
    console.log(networkDataId);
    network.fit();
    },
  height: 600,
  width: 1000
});
```

Comment: This is always returning the data-id of the first .info dialog. I want to get the data-id of the one I opened.

Comment: @Llama I don't know what context the `open` callback is giving you, so try replacing `.info` by `this`.

Comment: I managed to solve it with the event parameter the open function is giving me. thanks for helping me